# getting intersection points between two points

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

i have two points in canvas as in image 1 and 2.
I need to get its intersection points which is given in image as 3rd point.

How could i get this point.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, can't be done...two points are not sufficient constraints. Looks like you might have a quadratic Bezier curve there and you're looking for the control point.

Comment: +1. WHat you are looing for is the intersection between the incoming and the outgoing tangents of 2 points of a curve. In the BEzier case, that's your 3rd point. So your computation should be the opposite one : from the 3rd point, compute the tangents and the curve shape

Comment: If you have a particular quadratic curve you want to draw, ie you know the equation of the curve in red then you can find the equations of the tangents at 1 and 2 and hence find their intersection. if you are just experimenting with quadratic Bezier curves just choose points 1 and 2 and then look at the results for different points 3.